# In getServerSideProps, how to execute the return statement after all fetching is complete?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I have access to the username of a person and I can access their corresponding data object using one fetch from firebase. This data object has a lot of properties, including one which is called "uploads" which is an array of documentIDs where each id is that of a post uploaded by the user. I want to fetch all these documents, make it an array and return the ENTIRE array back to the page.

I have written this code so far: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC74t.png

What is happening is that the return on line 54 executes before all elements of postIDs is looped through because of which, an empty array is returned back to the component.

Let me know if further details are required. Please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I will keep that in mind for questions I ask in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your loop to a `for...of`:

```
for (const postID of currentUserData.uploads) {
    const postReference = doc(db, `posts/${postID}`)
    const snapshot = await getDoc(postReference)
    const postData = snapshot.data()
    postData.time = postData.time.toJSON()
    uploadsArray.push(postData)
}

return { props: { uploadsArray }}
```

Comment: This works magically well and does exactly what I wanted to. Thank you for your answer. Just as a follow up, what would be the theoretical difference between forEach and for...of loop?

Comment: The `forEach` loop expects sync code and it is not suited to work with `async await`. Check this docs for more info on its behaviour https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

What about try to use Promise.all?

```
var promises = [];
promises.push();

// Wait for all promises to resolve
Promise.all(promises).then(function(res) { 
    // Do something...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw a lot of answers to similar questions involving promise.all() but I have a hard time wrapping my head around its code.